# How to exclude the results from few filters

Tags: jira, jql

I have a few filters. Now I have to find other issues that are not included in this filter. I try the following JQL request

```
project = "Management" AND issuetype = Test AND status not in (closed) AND issue not in linkedIssuesInFilter(29971, 29875)
```

But as I understand I can't set few filter IDs in the brackets

**Found solution**

```
project = "Management" AND issuetype = Test AND status not in (closed) AND filter not in (29971, 29973, 29975, 29977, 29979, 29990)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can keep chaining with another `AND`. Also, you can write `status != closed` if you are only checking against one status, but your version works as well.

```
project = "Management" AND issuetype = Test AND status != closed AND issue not in linkedIssuesInFilter("29971") AND issue not in linkedIssuesInFilter("29875")
```